Slickgrid, collapse group does not hide data rows
I am working with the grouping feature of Slickgrid 5. Grouping works fine so far and also the hijacking of the click event on the group data line expands my groups. However, collapsing them does not work except from the icon being toggled. The data rows within this group are not hidden when I collapse the group.
This is the part of my code that expands the group but is not able to collapse it properly:
//click events
        View2.grid.onClick.subscribe(function (e, args) {   
            if($(e.target).closest(".slick-row").hasClass("slick-group")){
                //expand collapse categories
                var item = View2.gridDataView.getItem(args.row);
                if (item) {
                    if (!item.isCollapsed) {
                        // this should collapse the group, right?
                        item.isCollapsed = true;
                    } else {
                        item.isCollapsed = false;
                        //lazy load category entries
                        if(!item._contentIsLoaded){                         
                            item._contentIsLoaded = true;
                            View2.connectToServer(item.contentUrl, item.id);
                        }                       
                    }
                    View2.gridDataView.updateItem(item.id, item);
                }
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();

You see I have a more generic implementation within my own class where grid is the SlickGrid and gridDataView the dataView component itself.
I wonder what prevents the grid from hiding the group data rows in the marked line.

I'm not sure why you're using such custom code for grouping when the default code should work fine, but anyway don't forget to call grid.invalidate(); to invalidate all rows and force a re-render of the HTML.
